# How to set the fax caller id

Tags: php, twilio-api

I wnat to konw how to set the fax caller id.

To send a fax with Twilio Programmable Fax, I will use the Twilio Fax REST API,When I sending an outbound fax ,I need to set an Incoming Phone Number.

I want the receiver to see not the Incoming Phone Number, but my custom number or name. How do I set it up?

Is there any parameter that can set the caller ID?

```
$fax = $twilio->fax->v1->faxes
                   ->create("+15555555555", // to
                            "https://example.com", // mediaUrl
                            array("from" => "+15017122661")
                   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only set caller ID with Twilio verified numbers.

You can easily verify any number you want under the "phone numbers" tab on the left panel of the main console, then click on "verified caller ID"

Once you're number is verified you can enter it as the "From" number in your application from where you're sending the fax from